# drawing a square root sign with css

Tags: html, css

I would like to "draw" a scalable square root sign with CSS; my current attempt is:

```css
.root {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.radix1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.2em;
  height: 1.5ex;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-top: 0.2ex solid;
  border-right: 0.15ex solid;
  transform: skew(25deg);
}
.radix2 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-top: 0.2ex solid;
  border-left: 0.15ex solid;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
}
.radicand {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  transform: skew(15deg);
}
```

```html
<p>Lore ipsum
<span class="root">
  <span class="radix1"></span>
    <span class="radix2">
      <span class="radicand">
        2<var>xy</var>
      </span>
    </span>
</span>
lore ipsum.</p>
<p>Lore ipsum
<span class="root">
  <span class="radix1"></span>
    <span class="radix2">
      <span class="radicand">
        2<var>x y</var><br />2<var>pq</var>
      </span>
    </span>
</span>
lore ipsum.</p>
<p>Lore ipsum
<span class="root">
  <span class="radix1"></span>
    <span class="radix2">
      <span class="radicand">
        2<var>xy</var><br />2<var>pq</var><br />123,456,789
      </span>
    </span>
</span>
lore ipsum.</p>
```

(The line breaks in examples 2 and 3 are only simple replacements for larger arguments such as fractions, matrices etc.) 
My questions and wish list are:

- The two parts (radix1 and radix2 span) fit together (horizontally, at the bottom line) only in the first example. How can I insert additional margin(?) between radix1 and radix2 depending on the total height of the square root?
- How can I scale the height of radix1 depending on total height of the square root? (E.g. height: 40%; does not work, but would be nice.)
- And of course: Is there another way to do this (better)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try something like this by using only one element to create the root square. Then use a pseudo-element for the small part so you can easily adjust its position relative to the main part.

```css
.root {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  margin: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.root:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40%;
  width: 5px;
  left: -5px;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  transform: skew(30deg);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.radicand {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  transform: skew(15deg);
}
```

```html
<p>Lore ipsum
  <span class="root">
      <span class="radicand">
        2<var>xy</var>
</span></span> lore ipsum.</p>
<p>Lore ipsum
  <span class="root">
      <span class="radicand">
        2<var>x y</var><br>2<var>pq</var>

  </span> </span> lore ipsum.</p>
<p>Lore ipsum
  <span class="root">
      <span class="radicand">
        2<var>xy</var><br>2<var>pq</var><br>123,456,789
 
  </span> </span>lore ipsum.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! "transform-origin" helps as well with my original attempt, but the pseudo-element solution is much nicer. In particular, I can now scale the "before"-part as desired using, e.g., "height: 40%; width: 0.2em; left: -0.2em;"!

Comment: @O.Dietrich you can also scale with top/bottom .. for example you put bottom:0 and top:10px and you will always have it 10px from the top ;)

Comment: This approach is purely based on css right? There may produce any vulnerability issue if I use this code in android webview?

Answer (score 0):

"Is there a better way to do this?" Yes. If you import a JavaScript library such as MathJax, you can write your equations in LaTeX format. That way they'll display neatly, and on terminal browsers they'll appear as LaTeX which is relatively readable, rather than having the square root sign disappear without a trace.